# How to echo GROUP BY mysql in array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, group-by

I have this data

```
ID DATEREG     REQUEST
1  2016-10-24  PAPER
2  2016-10-24  PENCIL
3  2016-10-24  BALLPEN
4  2016-10-25  PAPER
5  2016-10-26  PENCIL
```

here's the query I use to calculate total request.

```
    $rows = '';
    $query = "SELECT id,count(*) as total,date,request FROM list GROUP BY date,request ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total_rows =  $result->num_rows;
    if($result) 
    {
    $rowsv1 = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    print "<pre>";
    echo print_r($rowsv1);
    print "</pre>";
    }
```

and example result which the request is only display 1(DESC order):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [total] => 3
        [datereg] => 2016-10-24
        [request] => PAPER
    )
```

I want to look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [total] => 3
        [datereg] => 2016-10-24
        [request1] => 1(total of PAPER)
        [request2] => 2(total of PENCIL)
        [request3] => 3(total of BALLPEN)
    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed your query a little so now firstly it groups by reques then by date. But you will have to aggregate the result in your php in order to have all 3 requests placed in one array item

```
   $query = "SELECT id,count(*) as total,date,request FROM list GROUP BY request, date ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Otherwise it will group by date which will lead to aggregating the result for a given date to only one request.